# Rolling Unique Sum for 3 previous months in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

The following is the dataset I am looking at.

```
Input:-
Date          Name
01/01/2017    A
01/03/2017    B
02/05/2017    A
03/17/2017    C
04/08/2017    D
05/10/2017    B
06/12/2017    D

Output:-
Date      Unique Count
Jan 2017    2
Feb 2017    2
Mar 2017    3
Apr 2017    3
May 2017    3
Jun 2017    2
```

I want to get unique counts of "Name" in previous 3 months on rolling basis. For example for date 06/12/2017 the previous 3 months including itself is april, May, June. So April had "D", May had "B" and June had "D". So the unique count of June Month is 2. Similarly for all the other months as well.

I am looking for a pandas function that could help me achieve this. Or any custom code that could implement this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How is the dataset present? In a file? Or as a list ? or a dictionary? how will it be given as input?

Comment: @s_vishnu it would be a dataframe, imported from a database from a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
months = pd.to_datetime(d.loc[:, "Date"]).dt.to_period("M")
out = pd.DataFrame([
    (month, len(d.loc[(-2 <= months - month) & (months - month <= 0), "Name"].unique()))
    for month in months.unique()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by creating the DataFrame and setting the dates as the index:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01-01-2017', '01-03-2017', '02-05-2017', '03-17-2017', '04-08-2017', '05-10-2017', '06-12-2017'], 
                  'Name': ['A','B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'D']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.set_index('Date')
```

First, we group by month so that later we can do rolling counts per month:

```
groups = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M'))
```

Now, we need a way to retain all names we've seen each month. We can put them into a list.

```
all_names_per_month = groups['Name'].apply(list)
```

This looks like:

```
Date
2017-01-31    [A, B]
2017-02-28       [A]
2017-03-31       [C]
2017-04-30       [D]
2017-05-31       [B]
2017-06-30       [D]
Freq: M, Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Next, ideally, we would want to use `all_names_per_month.rolling(3).apply(...)`, but unfortunately, `apply` doesn't work with non-numeric values, so we can instead define a custom rolling function to get us the values we want:

```
def get_values(window_len, df):
    values = []
    for i in range(1, len(df)+1):
        if i < window_len:
            values.append(len(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_names_per_month.iloc[0: i]))))
        else:
            values.append(len(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_names_per_month.iloc[i-3:i]))))

    return values


values = get_values(3, all_names_per_month)
```

This gives us:

```
[2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
```

Finally, we can put these values into a DataFrame with the appropriate index, which we then modify to look the way you specified above:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(data=values, columns=['Unique Count'], index=all_names_per_month.index)

result.index = result.index.strftime('%B %Y')

result 

               Unique Count
January 2017              2
February 2017             2
March 2017                3
April 2017                3
May 2017                  3
June 2017                 2
```